# OpenVPN icmp doesn't go all the way back

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I have

- server : 192.168.5.77
- openServerVPN : 192.168.5.202
- client1 : 10.8.1.2
- client2 : 10.8.0.3

When I ping server from client2 to server  :

```
server: tcpdump  icmp -n -q
14:41:32.689212 IP 192.168.5.202 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 12, seq 1, length 64
14:41:32.689257 IP 192.168.5.77 > 192.168.5.202: ICMP echo reply, id 12, seq 1, length 64
14:41:33.704333 IP 192.168.5.202 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 12, seq 2, length 64
14:41:33.704378 IP 192.168.5.77 > 192.168.5.202: ICMP echo reply, id 12, seq 2, length 64
openServerVPN tcpdump  icmp -n -q
16:41:32.691194 IP 10.8.0.3 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 12, seq 1, length 64
16:41:32.691573 IP 192.168.5.77 > 10.8.0.3: ICMP echo reply, id 12, seq 1, length 64
16:41:32.960443 IP 192.168.5.202 > 10.8.0.3: ICMP 192.168.5.202 udp port 53 unreachable, length 67
16:41:32.996227 IP 192.168.5.202 > 10.8.0.3: ICMP 192.168.5.202 udp port 53 unreachable, length 67
16:41:33.706305 IP 10.8.0.3 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 12, seq 2, length 64
16:41:33.706710 IP 192.168.5.77 > 10.8.0.3: ICMP echo reply, id 12, seq 2, length 64
```

The ping reply is coming back to client2

But when I ping from client1 the server doesnt seem to know where openServerVPN is :

```
server: tcpdump  icmp -n -q
14:39:04.889226 IP 192.168.5.202 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 48, length 64
14:39:04.889252 IP 192.168.5.77 > 192.168.5.202: ICMP echo reply, id 11, seq 48, length 64
14:39:05.912198 IP 192.168.5.202 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 49, length 64
14:39:05.912238 IP 192.168.5.77 > 192.168.5.202: ICMP echo reply, id 11, seq 49, length 64
14:39:06.911324 IP 192.168.5.202 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 50, length 64
14:39:06.911370 IP 192.168.5.77 > 192.168.5.202: ICMP echo reply, id 11, seq 50, length 64
14:39:07.496717 IP 192.168.5.202 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP host 192.168.5.202 unreachable, length 92
14:39:07.496739 IP 192.168.5.202 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP host 192.168.5.202 unreachable, length 92
14:39:07.496744 IP 192.168.5.202 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP host 192.168.5.202 unreachable, length 92
14:39:07.889982 IP 192.168.5.202 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 51, length 64

openServerVPN tcpdump  icmp -n -q
16:38:59.879419 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 43, length 64
16:39:00.902542 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 44, length 64
16:39:01.879307 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 45, length 64
16:39:02.888641 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 46, length 64
16:39:03.880365 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 47, length 64
16:39:04.890346 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 48, length 64
16:39:05.913296 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 49, length 64
16:39:06.912412 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 50, length 64
16:39:07.891099 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.77: ICMP echo request, id 11, seq 51, length 64
```

he got the good IP to reply to but the ping reply doesnt reach the openServerVPN.

IPTABLE openServerVPN :

```
    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.1.0/24          anywhere             ctstate NEW
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       all  --  10.8.1.0/24         !10.8.1.0/24          to:192.168.5.202
SNAT       all  --  10.8.0.0/24         !10.8.0.0/24          to:192.168.5.202
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.8.1.0/24          anywhere
```

**[edit]**

Also When I ping from client2 to openServerVPN it works

```
17:13:58.857825 IP 10.8.0.1 > 10.8.0.3: ICMP echo reply, id 16, seq 8, length 64
17:13:59.654237 IP 192.168.5.202 > 10.8.0.3: ICMP 192.168.5.202 udp port 53 unreachable, length 73
17:13:59.654300 IP 192.168.5.202 > 10.8.0.3: ICMP 192.168.5.202 udp port 53 unreachable, length 73
17:13:59.837156 IP 10.8.0.3 > 10.8.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 16, seq 9, length 64
17:13:59.837206 IP 10.8.0.1 > 10.8.0.3: ICMP echo reply, id 16, seq 9, length 64
```

but on client 1 to openServerVPN  it fails :

```
17:07:43.889960 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.202: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 17, length 64
17:07:44.897419 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.202: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 18, length 64
17:07:45.898396 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.202: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 19, length 64
17:07:46.900194 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.202: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 20, length 64
17:07:47.910821 IP 10.8.1.2 > 192.168.5.202: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 21, length 64
```

**[/edit]**

Do you know what/where I should look/try ?

Comment: Will you add the main routing tables from the server and openServerVPN? Also I see you are using both SNAT and MASQUERADE targets int the nat POSTROUTING chain, does openServerVPN have IP addresses other than the tunnel address 10.8.0.1 and the local address 192.168.5.202?

Comment: @cburn11 : I found out what the issue was : I was lacking a route from 10.8.1.0 to 10.8.0.1. To answer your question I don't have any other adresses than 10.8.0.1 and 192.168.5.202, why ?